# Centering text from drawstring

Tags: java, user-interface, drawstring

Soo the user is given the choice to choose whether the text "Welcome to Java Programming" text should be italic, bold, or centered in the panel. These choices are check boxes. I'm not sure how to make it so that when the user picks center, it'll be in the center.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
   super.paint(g);
   g.setColor(Color.black);
   g.drawRoundRect(75,90,324,120,10,10);
   g.drawLine(183,90,183,210);
   g.setColor(currentC);
   g.setFont(new Font(currentFont, intBold + intItalic, 24));
   g.drawString("Welcome to Java Programming",30,70);
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
  if(e.getSource() == checkBoxBold) { 
      if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
          intBold = Font.BOLD;
      if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
          intBold = Font.PLAIN;
  } 
  if(e.getSource() == checkBoxItalics) {
      if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
          intItalic = Font.ITALIC;
      if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
          intItalic = Font.PLAIN;
  }  
  if(e.getSource() == checkBoxCenter) {
      if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
         //PROBLEM RIGHT HERE
      if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)

  } 
  if(e.getSource() == radioRed)
      currentC = Color.red;
  else if(e.getSource() == radioGreen)
      currentC = Color.green;
      else if(e.getSource() == radioBlue)
          currentC = Color.blue;
  if(e.getSource() == fontChoice)
      currentFont = fontNames[fontChoice.getSelectedIndex()];
  repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *FontMetrics*:

```
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
```

To get width of your text use:

```
fm.stringWidth(text)
```

Then output your text at

```
width / 2 - fm.stringWidth(text) / 2
```

Where *width* is a width of your output area.